# Grails 3 Static Resource Cache Configuration

Tags: grails, caching, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

My Grails 3 website includes many static resources like js and css, I found all these static resources are set to "no-cache" and "max-age=0" by default, which cause every time reloading the page, all these static resources have to be downloaded again, this causes significant performance problem.

I am using asset-pipeline to manage these static resources in application.js and application.css, how can I configure the cache setting so that the browser can cache the static resources?

[image: Cache]

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10410#issuecomment-273220646

Just add

```
grails.resources.cachePeriod: your value
```

to your application.yml

Comment: Where is the documentation about this?
I'm trying this without success:

`grails:
    resources:
        cachePeriod: 604800`

Comment: While this works, I cannot find documentation on what unit "your value" should be in except that it's an integer